# Como faço para limitar a quantidade de linhas de uma listview

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma listview que e adaptada com um cursoradapter ...ele seleciona tudo do banco de dados e adaptar na minha listview .... mas queria limitar a quantidades de linhas que aparecen na minha listview ... mais ou menos assim .. queria q selecionase todos os dados que tenho mas que mostrase so 10 ... independente do numero de dados no banco .... obrigado

Comment: Você está usando SimpleAdapter ou CustomAdapter para seu ListView? Seria interessante você colocar algo do seu código aqui.

Comment: Pode limitar as linhas diretamente na consulta a base de dados, que é mais simples

Comment: Use o LIMIT e faça sua regra direto no banco de dados!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta limitar na consulta SQL ao banco. No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT coluna FROM tabela ORDER BY algo LIMIT 10
```

Se estiver usando o método query() da classe SqliteDatabase, pode fazer a mesma query acima dessa forma:

```
db.query (null, 
            tabela, 
            New String[]{coluna}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            algo, 
            "10");
```